# Why does automating SFTP with Expect hang after sending the password?

Tags: linux, automation, passwords, sftp, expect

I am attempting to automate uploading some files from my Linux server to an FTP-enabled Windows server. I am successfully doing so manually using SFTP and then issuing the *put* command. However, when called from cron, my script keeps stopping for a password.

Below is the code I am attempting to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#!/bin/sh
clear
spawn sftp remoteuser@43.123.0.10
expect "password"
send "world"
expect eof
```

As it stands, it stops each time to request a password. Why doesn't `send "world"` complete the password dialog?

**UPDATE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#!/bin/sh
clear
spawn sftp remoteuser@43.123.0.10
expect "remoteuser@43.123.0.10's password:"
send "world"
expect eof
```

Now I get the following error:

```
xml_reports.sh: line 5: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "remoteuser@43.123.0.10's password:": no such file or directory
xml_reports.sh: line 7: send: command not found
couldn't read file "eof": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is the password request using a capital letter? if so, then you need to use expect "[Pp]assword"

Comment: @Petesh, really you want to send a carriage return (`\r`) -- that simulates the user hitting Enter.

Comment: @glennjackman removed the offending comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn sftp remoteuser@XX.XX.XX.XX
expect \"password\"
send \"PASSWORD\r\"
interact "
```

Example : http://www.techtrunch.com/scripting/lazy-admins-part-2

Comment: Thank you. The answer was spot-on and the link looks very informative too. Thanks

Comment: You should use a here-doc literal instead of having to escape all your inner quotes and variables: `expect -c <<'END'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arguments when you run it. Read [this](http://code.seanodonnell.com/?id=21) article. It explains how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is Expect is still waiting for the pattern to arrive (until timeout), it could be that "password" is not in the prompt of sftp  and that it could be "Password" or something else.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the Expect argument had to be exact. I took your advice and updated my code but I got some errors. I have included an UPDATE section in my original question with the changes and the error output