# Linux Expect SFTP + put file

Tags: linux, upload, sftp, expect, put

I just got some help in automating my password input during an **SFTP** connection by using **Expect**.

I then tried to issue a put command and things got complicated again. I'm using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#!/bin/sh

expect -c "
spawn sftp remoteuser@*.*.*.*
expect \"remoteuser@*.*.*.*'s password:\"
send \"passwrd\r\"
interact "

echo "put output/data.xml\r"
echo "quit\r"
```

My password input and connection to the remote server works just fine but I am struggling to get the *put output/data.xml* command to display and execute at the SFTP prompt.

My **echo "put output/data.xml\r"** and **echo "quit\r"** lines just print as text which is not entirely surprising but I really don't know what else might work.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159935/why-does-automating-sftp-with-expect-hang-after-sending-the-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you need some help, but you should at least try doing some reading. When you say `expect -c 'some stuff ...'`, you are specifying the *entire* expect script as the parameter to the `-c` option. The Expect session will not exist afterward.

Also, try to understand what the `interact` command does instead of blindly applying what someone advises.

Anyway, the solution:

```
expect  <<'END_EXPECT'
set timeout -1
spawn sftp remoteuser@1.2.3.4
expect "[Pp]assword:"
send "passwrd\r"
expect "whatever the sftp prompt looks like"
send "put output/data.xml\r"
expect "whatever the sftp prompt looks like"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

Note that the here-doc delimiter is quoted when you first see it. That way, you will not be subjected to any shell expansions. It's like the entire here-doc is single-quoted.

Comment: I had to remove the `-c` option, but otherwise this works great!